# Javascript to save form values in users browser incase session expires

Tags: php, javascript, forms, session, save

Currently working on some other aspects of my project, but while I do so I was hoping to get some information on a problem I will be working on very shortly.  After a very brief search didn't turn up anything immediately I thought I would leave the question here to see if anyone else has cleverly solved this issue.

Heres the problem:

We a developing a very typical CMS yet with some higher profile clients that require higher security then most CMS' that handle personal blogs, therefore the user sessions must expire to help in preventing session hijacking.  Currently set at 20 minutes, but we would like to set it to more to 10 minutes of inactivity.  The problem would come up if the client is say, writing a big article, or taking a looong time to fill out a form, when they click to save, if their session has expired they will loose all their data.  That would make for some very nasty emails I'm sure!

Has anyone come up with a nice solution to this?  My thoughts were to have a javascript automaticlly save form data to the users browser (possibly as a cookie) every few minutes, and when the users session expires, after they log in and go back to the page, the javascript would fill out the form again.  After a successful POST the javascript would clear itself.

Thoughts from the SO community?

Answer (score 1):

[jsper](https://github.com/rmcvey/jsper) or another library like it would be a good bet; it allows you to save data in the browser and supports all browsers (back to IE6) using localStorage, cookies, data attributes, etc.